# Starting emulator for JavaME in NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java-me, emulation

I've just installed NetBeans IDE 7.1 full with J2ME SDK. When I started any project, the emulator can not start, and there is an error message:

```
Failed to connect to device 0!
Reason:
Emulator 0 failed to register in time!
C:\Users\Comp1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MobileApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:782: Execution failed with error code 1.
```

By searching on Google, I tried the following ways but do not succeed:

- Turn off Windows Firewall
- Add runMidlet.exe to the system DEP
- Turn off Anti-virus software (only Avira is installed on my machine)

Please help me. Thank you in advanced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following steps,

- Go To Tool Menu , Select Java Platforms
- Click on "Add Platform" Button
- Select Second Option "Java ME MIDP Platform Emulator, Click on Next Button
- Select your SDK / Wireless Toolkit folder path.

Now try executing your project again.